# How to insert client ip source inside FTP payload

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, payload, ftp-server

I've scenario where ftp client and server are separe with a proxy server.
I want to insert ip source address into ftp client payload so that the ftp server can retrieve it.
The problem is that i don't know how to proceed.
Help me out please.
With regards.

Comment: What do you mean by *"FTP packet"*? FTP does not have "packets". It's text-based protocol. You should better describe the functionality, that you want to achieve, rather than asking such technicality. It looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Your edit didn't improve anything. I'm downvoting your question, until you explain us, what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. My goal is to insert Ip adress inside ftp client  payload  so that the ftp server can extract that

Comment: FTP server knows where (what IP) the connection comes from. That's a basic principle of whole Internet!

Comment: OK, and all that information should have been in your question from the very first moment! + Do you have a control over both the server and the client? Can you change/re-implement both?

Comment: Yes but when NAT is applied, the ftp server does not know the source not necessarily the original ip

Comment: We understand your problem now. So edit your question so say all that!

Comment: Yes the goal is to re-implement both

Comment: There are also approaches such as the [`PROXY` protocol](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt), assuming your client and server could understand it.  The benefit of using `PROXY` is that it's not quite home-grown...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP is text-based protocol.

If you can re-implement both the client and the server, just make them understand a new command for your purpose.

E.g. you can have the client send a `XIP` command just after authentication (or even before, if you need):

```
XIP 203.0.113.0
```

The server will just parse the IP and respond something like this (to follow the FTP specification):

```
200 OK
```

And then carry on as in a normal FTP session.